# flutter ddd firebase course (reso coder) problem with nested class in entity and data transfer object

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to use the ddd architecture explained by reso coder in my project.but when i tried to nest a class into another class for both the entity and the data transfer object it doesn't work. i have tried everything i know, searched but no result.

**this is the entity file**

```
    @freezed
abstract class Post implements _$Post {
  const Post._();
  const factory Post({
    required UniqueId id,
    required User author,
    required VideoUrl videoUrl,
    required Caption caption,
  }) = _Post;

  factory Post.empty() => Post(
        id: UniqueId(),
        caption: Caption(''),
        videoUrl: VideoUrl(''),
        author: User.empty(),
      );

  Option<ValueFailure<dynamic>> get failureOption {
    return caption.failureOrUnit
        .andThen(videoUrl.failureOrUnit)
        .fold((f) => some(f), (_) => none());
  }
}
```

**this is the dto file**

```
    @freezed
abstract class PostDto implements _$PostDto {
  const PostDto._();
  const factory PostDto({
    required String id,
    required UserDto author,
    required String videoUrl,
    required String caption,
    //required DateTime date,
  }) = _PostDto;

  factory PostDto.fromDomain(Post post) {
    return PostDto(
      id: post.id.getOrCrash(),
      author: ,
      videoUrl: post.videoUrl.getOrCrash(),
      caption: post.caption.getOrCrash(),
      // date: Timestamp.fromDate(date),
    );
  }

  Post toDomain() {
    return Post(
      id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(id),
      author: ,
      caption: Caption(caption),
      videoUrl: VideoUrl(videoUrl),
    );
  }

  factory PostDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PostDtoFromJson(json);

 
}
```

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well an obvious problem in your file is:

```
author: ,
```

in both the `PostDto` factory as well as the `Post toDomain()` method.

But without further details it is harder to guess.

If I would guess further. I would say you should have something like this instead:

```
author: UserDto.fromDomain(post.author),
```

and:

```
author: author.toDomain(),
```

And of course implement those methods.

Furthermore, you are probably getting warnings that the abstract keyword is no longer required if you are using the latest versions of freezed and freezed_annotation.